# error: The return type 'Iterable<Book>' isn't a 'List<Book>', as required by the closure's context. in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

"listOfDocSnap.map((docSnap) => Book.fromMap(docSnap.data())));" I am getting error on line:

error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

and

error: The return type 'Iterable' isn't a 'List', as required by the closure's context.

Book class:

```
class Book {
  final String bookName;
  final String id;
  final String authorName;
  final Timestamp publishedDate;

  Book(
      {required this.bookName,
      required this.id,
      required this.authorName,
      required this.publishedDate});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'id': id,
        'bookName': bookName,
        'authoName': authorName,
        'publishedDate': publishedDate,
      };

  factory Book.fromMap(Map map) => Book(
      bookName: map['bookName'],
      id: map['id'],
      authorName: map['authorName'],
      publishedDate: map['publishedDate']);
}
```

View model class:

```
class BooksViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Database _database = Database();

  Stream<List<Book>> getBookList() {
    const String booksRef = 'books';

    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> streamListDocument =
        _database.getBooks(booksRef).map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs);

    Stream<List<Book>> streamListOfBook = streamListDocument.map(
        (listOfDocSnap) =>
            ***listOfDocSnap.map((docSnap) => Book.fromMap(docSnap.data())));***

    return streamListOfBook;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

map returns Iterable so you need to call .toList()

```
listOfDocSnap.map<Book>((docSnap) => Book.fromMap(docSnap.data()))).toList();
```

Comment: This is how i solved, thx: (listOfDocSnap) => listOfDocSnap
            .map((docSnap) =>
                Book.fromMap(docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList()